# Configuring Netgear Ethernet Switch using Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, networking, switches

I want to use my raspberry pi as a way of configuring my switch.

My switch is a Netgear brand switch.

The issue I have is that the network itself is not connected to the internet and the RPI is connected to the switch only via an Ethernet cable.

Is this possible? Or should I look for a different approach.

Comment: Ah, let me see. I am using for my home LAN, the following NetGear WifFi router. I am not sure if it can be called a "switch": (1) "Amazon NETGEAR Smart WiFi Router with Dual Band Gigabit for Amazon Echo/Alexa - AC1750 (R6400-100NAS) - $62.90":
https://www.amazon.com/NETGEAR-Smart-Router-Gigabit-Amazon/dp/B00Z0V2NQ8/ref=sr_1_16?qid=1559215335&refinements=p_89%3ANETGEAR&s=pc&sr=1-16. / to continue, ...

Comment: To answer you question, I need first to read the user manual to refresh my memory of how didiI configure my WiFi router: (2) NetGear AC1750 Smart WiFi Router Model R6400 User Manual":
http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/R6400/R6400_UM_07Aug2015.pdf. /to continue, ...

Comment: Now I am reading the manual to refresh my memory on how to do the hardware setup, ie, the wiring thing: (3) https://imgur.com/gallery/KRwx2Je. / To continue, ...

Comment: Now I am reading the Network user manual page 15, with instructions of connecting your computer (WinPC or Rpi) to "the Network".  There are two ways to connect to the Network: (1) Wired connection, using Ethernet cable, (2) Wireless/WiFi connection, using either (a) WPS to connect to the Network, or (b)  Use your computer to find and select the Network. / to continue, ...

Comment: @tlfong01 Thanks for your replies. I am using a NETGEAR ProSafe with a model number of GS105E

Comment: Now let me come back to your question: "If you are not connected to the Internet, how can you configure your NetGear WiFi router using your Rpi (or WinPC) which is connected to the NetGear router?" To answer you question, you need to tell me if you understand the terms "DHCP", and “WPS" etc. Ah, supper time, see you later. Hope other guys might help you.

Comment: @Lyra Orwell, thank you for your router details. I have been using a couple of NetGear router models these couple of years. If yours is 2.4G/5G compatible, then my limited experience is that the setup/configuration is basically similar. I am suing my model and user guide just as an example or case study. You can compare your user guide with mine to see if my suggestions are applicable to your situation. If not, then perhaps I can skim your user guide to see if I should modify my suggestions. Ah supper time, see you late this evening or tomorrow. Good luck and Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01 Here are the guides related to my switch https://www.netgear.com/support/product/GS105E.aspx#docs

Comment: @Lyra Orwell. I skimmed the documents of your switch and found the following most useful to answer your question: "NetGear ProSAFE Plus Configuration Utility User Manual":
http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/GS105E/ProSAFE_Plus_Utility_UM_EN.pdf. After reading the manual, I conclude the following (1) You don't need to connect to the Internet to configure your switch, (2) However, you CANNOT, as you said you want in your question: "use Rpi to configure the switch". (3) You can only use the above WinPC GUI utility to config the switch, / to continue, ...

Comment: (4) But if you can assess the Internet, you can use a web browser, instead of the WinPC GUI utility to do the configuration. There are other complications, such as if you have a DHCP server. Anyway, I think using the (offline) WinPC based GUI "ProSAFE Plus Configuration Utility" is the simplest way, at the same time, meeting your no Internet connected requirements. I don't see why using the alternative (online) browser to do the same job is better. I must confess my only experience is in WiFi router with switches, but NO experience in switch without router. / to continue, ...

Comment: By the way, if you can let us know your application, eg 5 Rpi's interconnected by the 5 port switch, and the Rpi's can talk to each other in LAN, no WAN required etc, then perhaps we can make other suggestions. Cheers.

Comment: Ref: (1) "NetGear GS105E 5 Port Gigabit Ethernet SM Plus Switch (End of life)": 
https://www.netgear.com/support/product/GS105E.aspx#docs,

(2) "NetGear Gigabit Ethernet Switch Product Datasheet":
https://www.netgear.com/images/datasheet/switches/Gigabit_Ethernet_Smart_Managed_Plus_Switches_DS.pdf,
 
(3) "NetGear Gigabit Ethernet Switch Installation Guide":
http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/GS105E/GS105E_IGprt_24Sept12.pdf,

(4) "NetGear ProSAFE Plus Configuration Utility User Manual":
http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/GS105E/ProSAFE_Plus_Utility_UM_EN.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your switch but it must have an interface for manageing it, sometimes with an extra serial connection, but mostly with a connection through any of its ethernet ports. You should always find a text console on the management connection but most modern switches also provide a http interface that you can use with an internet browser. With the RasPi connected to the switch you should be able to use the text console of the switch with **telnet**, or **ssh**. To use the http interface just put the initial ip address of the switch into the internet browser address line and connect. Details about these connections, e.g. initial ip address, telnet and ssh password etc. you should find in the manual of the switch.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manuals from the link you posted:

> Plus switches are plug and play.You can install a configuration utility to select additional options to manage and customize the switch for your network. This utility is on the resource CD that was shipped with the switch.
> Note: The configuration utility is installed on your computer and is only supported on Windows.

Fortunately, for those not using windows:

> Instead of using the ProSAFE Plus Utility, you can also access and configure a NETGEAR Smart Managed Plus switch directly using a web browser and the switch’s web browser–based management interface. For more information, see the NETGEAR Smart Managed Plus Switches User Manual or a user manual that is specific to your switch model.

It would be worth taking Netgears offer up:

> Complimentary Support

> NETGEAR provides complimentary technical support for NETGEAR products for 90 days from the original date of purchase.

This can be done by contacting them on [this site](https://www.netgear.com/support/contact.aspx)